# Number of ways to divide a group of 20 mice

Tags: combinatorics

> A medical researcher needs to divide a group of 20 white mice into two control groups of 10 each. In how many ways can this be done?

I found the answer to be $\binom{20}{10}$.
What would have been the question if the answer were to be $\binom{20}{10}$ * 2?

Comment: The first group has 10 from 20 choice ,$\left(\begin{array}{c}20\\ 10\end{array}\right)$ but the second group has no choice ,for the second we have $\left(\begin{array}{c}20-10\\ 10\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}10\\ 10\end{array}\right)=1$

Comment: Yes. I understood that part. I am trying to understand if the answer were $\binom{20}{10}$ * 2 ,what would be the question for such answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to be crystal clear in the thinking

**With both the mice and groups distinguishable (i.e. labelled)**

There are $\binom{20}{10}$ ways to choose group $A$.
Group $B$ gets formed automatically, or we can write $\binom{20}{10}\binom{10}{10}$

---

**With mice distinguishable, but groups indistinguishable**

answer becomes $\binom{20}{10}/2$

Suppose e.g. there were two mice, $X$ and $Y,$ $\binom21$  represents choosing one mouse from the two, but it doesn't matter which we choose first, so there is only one way to divide here into two groups.

---

**Question to match answer of $\binom{20}{10}*2$**

Both mice and groups are distinguishable,
**and we want to select one of the groups for a particular experiment**

Answer (score 2):

> A medical researcher needs to divide a group of 20 white mice into two
>   groups to conduct consecutive experiments. In how many ways can the
>   researcher choose the group for the first experiment?

Comment: So is it like there has to be a clear distinction between groups?

Comment: Yup. Order matters.

Answer (score 1):

> A medical researcher has $2$ initial groups of $20$ mice each. He needs to pick $1$ group and then divide it into $2$ control groups of 10 each. In how many ways can this be done?

1. Step: $2$ ways to pick the initial group.
2. Step: $\dbinom{20}{10}$ ways to pick $10$ mice from that product.

By the multiplication principle, the total number of ways to do it, is $$2\cdot\dbinom{20}{10}$$

Comment: From both answers here, I understand that there has to be a clear distinction between groups for my required answer. Whereas in my question, I am just dividing into groups without caring for the distinction. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: I believe that you make following thought: Let's divide the $20$ in $2$ groups of $10$ and then let just pick one group (2 possibilities). Hence, you want to multiple with $2$ in the end. Is that what you are thinking?

Comment: I am thinking,  Let's divide the 20 in 2 groups of 10. With the chosen 10 I can put them in group1 or group2. Hence the 2 multiplication.

Comment: Ok. I understand. But then the ways to divide the $20$ in $2$ groups of $10$ are not $\dbinom{20}{10}$ but only $\frac{\dbinom{20}{10}}{2!}$ because otherwise it is as if orders matters, i.e. as if the first group is the group that goes to the experiment and the other not. But order does not matter.